# How can an object become callable like a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So as long as anything in Javascript is actually an object, what makes an object behave as a function? What internal properties and labels make an object behave as an object we can call instead of just using it to store values?

Comment: Can you provide sample code

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Comment: Only native functions and things created from the Function constructor/class are functions. You cannot convert a non-function object into a function

Comment: If an object implements the internal [[Call]] method, then it will be callable: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an internal property, `[[Call]]`, which determines what will be executed when the object is called.

Plain objects don't have this internal property, so they are not callable, and **can not be made callable**.

The only callables in JS are:

- functions (which are also objects),
- classes (which are actually functions, and therefore objects as well), and
- Proxy objects that wrap callables.

To create a callable object, you must create a function and make it have the properties and prototypes you want.

Answer (score 4):

> So as long as anything in javascript is actually an object

Well, not everything in JavaScript is an object. For instance, primitives such as strings, booleans and numbers are not objects. JavaScript just wraps these primitives in objects when properties are accessed.

> what makes an object behave as a function what internal properties and
>   labels did this job to make an object behave as an execution code
>   instead of just storing variables

You're correct about functions being objects, however, unlike regular objects which just store key-value pairs, function objects have a special internal method which they implement known as [`[[Call]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist). This call method is what executes the code associated with the function object and is invoked when you call a function (`func_name()`). So, any object which implements the internal `[[Call]]` method is *callable*. You yourself cannot make an object callable by implementing this property as it is not part of the ECMAScript language itself, but rather a method name used by the spec. Instead, we use the `function` keyword for that. Function objects are still objects at the end of the day, so you can assign properties to them as well as access preexisting properties:

```js
function foo(a) {
  return a;
}

foo.bar = "foobar";
console.log(foo.length); // able to access pre-existing properties
console.log(foo.bar); // able to access our own properties
console.log(foo(2)); // able to invoke (due to [[Call]])
```

You can read more about function objects [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-6)

Answer (score 2):

You could assign an object to a function to get a callable function.

```js
var object = { foo: 42 },
    callable = Object.assign(function () {}, object);

console.log(callable)
console.log(callable())
console.log(Object.keys(callable));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an object callable.

You can add properties to an already existing `Function` object though. You will still retain `call()` behavior, but can also get and set properties.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object = { increment: function(x){
    return x+1
} ,
foo: 'foo'
    
};
var decrement = function(x){
    return x-1
}
    callable = Object.assign(decrement, object);

console.log(callable.increment(12)) //13
console.log(callable(67)) //66
console.log(Object.keys(callable));//[ 'increment', 'foo' ]
```

Answer (score -3):

There are different `prototypes` in javascript. E.g. `Object.prototype`, `Function.prototype`, `Array.prototype`. Javsacript works based on `prototypical inheritance`. This defines what is the `type` of any `object`.

When you create a function, its `__proto__` (also called as "dunder proto") is set to `Function.prototype`. Basically a function inherits from `Function.prototype` which in turn inherits from `Object.prototype`. Following example is taken from MDN. (Note - I think `__proto__` is not standardized. `Object.getPrototypeOf` should be used)

```
function f() {
  return 2;
}

// Functions inherit from Function.prototype 
// (which has methods call, bind, etc.)
// f ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

MDN has a great explanation for `prototypical inheritance`. For more information read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: This has very little to do with the question. You can set object `[[Prototype]]` to be `Function.prototype` but this wont make your object magically a callable. For example `var o = {}; Object.setPrototypeOf(o, Function.prototype); console.log(o instanceof Function);` logs true but `o()` fails.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks for pointing this out. I was just answering `internal properties` which makes an object a `function`. I think this is a part of the question. So, everything finally inherits from `Object.prototype` but `Function.prototype` makes it a function. Isn't it ?

Comment: Not really. It has nothing to do with prototype. As of now the thing that makes object callable is internal `[[Call]]` method not that prototype. Consider `var o = function() { console.log('I am still callable')}; Object.setPrototypeOf(o, null); console.log(o instanceof Function, Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === null); o()`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Again thanks for the information. I tried this `let o = function() {};
let b = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(b, Object.getPrototypeOf(o));
b.__proto__.call() --> returns undefined
let c = {};
c.__proto__.call(); --> returns error`. So atleast `__proto__.call` is added when you set the `prototype`. Not sure if it really makes sense to convert an `object` into a `callable function`. So whatever javascript is doing is right.

Comment: @Aditya 
i don't really understand your last comment about the  ```__proto__.call```
how can this be of any benefit .

Comment: @MahmoudSalah There is no benefit .. I just pointed out that `.call` is provided by `Function.prototype` which is available on object `c` in above code.