In js, is there any feature can implement callable instance, like __call__ method in python
In python, you can make an instance become a callable obj, like below shows:
# py code snippet

class Demo:
    def __call__(self):
        print("Demo's instance callable")

Demo()()  # Demo's instance is callable

In js, is there the same feature like shown above?
// js code snippet

function Demo1() {}
const d1 = new Demo1();

class Demo2 {}
const d2 = new Demo2();

// can I make d1 or d2 become a callable instance? like d1() or d2() to run some function logic.

Another question:
What property or feature on Function or Function.prototype, make it's instance is callable? Since I cant find any point of it on MDN Function page

You might be better off just defining a function and adding properties to it. Otherwise you can mess around with returning a proxy with an apply-trap from your constructor if you want to explore that path (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66584898/5648954)

@NickParsons thanks for ur info, it's seems like Proxy/Reflect would be a good approach. user2804429's answer also mention using the Reflect API.

Regarding your second question, an object is callable if it has an internal [[Call]] property defined, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60040421/5648954

@NickParsons oh another knowledge blind spot of js for me. anyway you are like js mentor on stackoverflow haha...

Here is another related question and answers which instead of a class based approach encourage a factory function which creates a special function that features custom object criteria in addition to the ones a function already comes with ... "How does one use an object as a function or how does one best create a custom callable object/type?"

You can not do that. But you can achieve something like that...
Here's my recommendation:


// Define your object with as many properties as needed.
const AnyObject =
{
  get Myself ()
  {
    return this;
  }
};

// Define a callable function which can't be arrow function if you
// want to use the this keyword pointing to the defined object.
const UnboundCallable = function ()
{
  console.log('The value of this.Myself is:', this?.Myself);
}

// Define a bound callable which points the this keyword to itself.
const BoundCallable = UnboundCallable.bind(UnboundCallable);

// Set your defined object as the prototype of the unbound callable.
Reflect.setPrototypeOf(UnboundCallable, AnyObject);

// Set your defined object as the prototype of the bound callable.
Reflect.setPrototypeOf(BoundCallable, AnyObject);

// You'll actually use the BoundCallable which behaves the best like
// you intend it to.

// You can also do this:
class Demo
{
  get Myself ()
  {
    return this;
  }
  
  constructor ()
  {
    const UnboundCallable = function CallableDemoObject ()
    {
      console.log('The value of this.Myself is:', this?.Myself);
    }
    
    const BoundCallable = UnboundCallable.bind(UnboundCallable);
    
    Reflect.setPrototypeOf(UnboundCallable, this);
    Reflect.setPrototypeOf(BoundCallable, this);
    
    return BoundCallable;
  }
}

///// TESTS /////

const MyDemo = new Demo;

MyDemo();
// Outputs:
// The value of this.Myself is:  [object Function]

console.log( MyDemo.Myself );
// Outputs:
// [object Function]

console.log( MyDemo.name );
// Outputs:
// bound CallableDemoObject

console.log( 'MyDemo is instance of Demo?', MyDemo instanceof Demo );
// Outputs:
// MyDemo is instance of Demo? true

console.log( 'MyDemo is instance of Function?', MyDemo instanceof Function );
// Outputs:
// MyDemo is instance of Function? false

console.log( 'Type of MyDemo:', typeof MyDemo );
// Outputs:
// Type of MyDemo: function

console.log( 'UnboundCallable is instanceof Function?', UnboundCallable instanceof Function );
// Outputs:
// UnboundCallable is instanceof Function? false

console.log( 'Type of UnboundCallable:', typeof UnboundCallable );
// Outputs:
// Type of UnboundCallable: function

UnboundCallable();
// Outputs:
// The value of this.Myself is: undefined

// The above happens because the this keyword inside the function is
// the actual context of the variable that reference the function.
// In Node, if in top level then the this keyword will be undefined.
// In any case, it will return anything other than undefined if the
// referenced value in this has Myself.

console.log( UnboundCallable.Myself );
// Outputs:
// [object Function]

// The above happens because even if the function is unbound, its
// prototype is still AnyObject. Myself is a getter that returns
// the this value which points to the function itself.

BoundCallable();
// Outputs:
// The value of this.Myself is: [object Function]

// The above happens because the function is bound and its this
// keyword points to itself. As the function have the AnyObject
// as its prototype, its Myself getter will return this which
// points to the function itself.

console.log( BoundCallable.Myself );
// Outputs:
// [object Function]

// The above happens because even if the function is bound and its
// prototype is still AnyObject. Myself is a getter that returns
// the this value which points to the function itself.

console.log( BoundCallable.name );
// Outputs:
// bound UnboundCallable



You'll actually use the BoundCallable as your object which behaves the best like you intend it to.
NOTE: As the generated function object prototype is a prototype of an object and not a function, then BoundCallable and CallableDemoObject don't pass the test instanceof Function, but they're still function in a typeof statement.

really nice example and code comment, pretty thanks.

@Lucas, I just finished the editing... The Demo class should help you pretty much. Note that if the bound function becomes a prototype of anything it will be a little tricky to call it.

oh another thing, do you have any clue: what property or feature on Function or Function.prototype, make it's instance is callable?

All subjects where typeof Subject == 'function' result in true are callable. All subjects where Subject instanceof Function result in true have the Function.prototype as one of its prototypes. All functions that have the prototype property (like function () {} and not like () => {}) should be instantiable like new ( function () {} ). If you wish to test if your subject is callable and an object instance but not a static class, then test like this: ( typeof Subject == 'function' ) && ! ( Subject instanceof Function ).

@Lucas See the other comment that I didn't mention you. Also, I just edited the snippet to show that MyDemo is a function but is also an instance of Demo. Which means that MyDemo instanceof Demo results in true and also typeof MyDemo results in function.

You can't call this directly, d1 and d2 are Demo instances, I recommend you to look at what happens in the process of new keyword in js, so you can understand, this is the implementation of the call method you described the code


function Demo1() {
    return function() {
        console.log(1)
    }
}
const d1 = new Demo1();

class Demo2 {}
const d2 = new Demo2();

d1()



I recommend you take a look at what the new keyword does so you can understand it

In js, function foo() {} or const foo = () => {}; Object.prototype.toString.call(foo);  // '[object Function]' as these shows js function or anonymous functions is an instance of Function class. I mean what property or feature on Function or Function.prototype, make it's instance is callable? and also I dont want constructor return an Function instance, I just want get a class instance like js plain object like { prop1, prop2, method1, method2 }.
